# SwiftyDropbox demo working on simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox

I've been successfully able to get the SwiftyDropBox demo
from:  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#tutorial
working on the Xcode (7.3) simulator, but when I try and run it on
tethered iphone6 (9.3.1) it has problems.

The ip6 run goes through the same series of Dropbox login
screens - "Link to Dropbox" -> "appXYZ would like access" -> Allow

After hitting Allow - it kicks out of the App - no useful debugs on
the console.  In the simulator, I get
the same set of screens, but ultimately get successful login - and can later pass the upload/download of the test file.

I've tried removing the DB app from the iPhone to make it more 
apples-to-apples, but still get the same result.

Would appreciate any thoughts/advice on this !

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what you tried so far. Also take the [tour] and read [ask] ;)

Comment: I believe I've solved the problem I was having.  The Dropbox key which I was using was generated with a different application name - this seems to have the problem with the redirect back to my app after login credentials were established.  I created an app from scratch following the DB boilerplate and it work fine on simulator and Iphone.  After renaming my App bundle name and getting a new DB key code, I'm getting successfully redirected back to my app after login credentials on DB are established. The old app resided on the iPhone and not on the sim - causing the redirect difference.